# Proof of formula for the the divergence of a totally anti-symmetric rank (2,0) tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I would like to prove that

$$\nabla_\mu T^{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_\mu\left(\sqrt{|g|}T^{\mu\nu}\right)$$

Given that $T^{\mu\nu}$ is totally anti-symmetric. I know that

$$\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\rho}T^{\rho\nu} + \Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\rho}T^{\mu\rho}$$

and that

$$\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\rho} = \partial_\mu \ln\sqrt{|g|}$$.

So my idea is to eliminate the term $\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\rho}T^{\mu\rho}$ and apply the above formula, however I am having difficulties to do so. I suspect I have to take advantage of the anti-symmetry of $T^{\mu\nu}$. Any help in working this out would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right in thinking that the antisymmetry of $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the key. The term you want to eliminate can be rewritten as follows:
$$ \Gamma^\nu_{\mu\rho}T^{\mu\rho} = \Gamma^\nu_{\rho\mu}T^{\rho\mu} = \Gamma^\nu_{\mu\rho}T^{\rho\mu} = \Gamma^\nu_{\mu\rho}\left(-T^{\mu\rho}\right) = -\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\rho}T^{\mu\rho}, $$ which implies that this term vanishes.

For clarity: I relabelled the summation indices, used the symmetry of $\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\rho}$ (as I assume you are working with the Levi-Civita connection), and used the antisymmetry of $T^{\mu\rho}$.

I take it from your question that you see how to prove the formula from there.

Comment: Thank you, I am indeed using the Levi-Civita connection. I think I can prove It now. In case of doubt I shall post a comment.